# convert the python dictionary output into a flowchart

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary, tkinter, flowchart

I have a file (see status variable in the code below) that I want to convert into a flowchart (attached). My python script converts "status" into a dictionary. How do I convert that dictionary into a flowchart or a graphic?
my code:

```
status = """
Object car {
Name honda;
From Richland;
To Seattle;
Distance 160;
Configuration road_travel;
}

Object bus {
Name greyhound;
From pasco;
To richland;
Distance 15;
Configuration road_travel;
}

Object aeroplane {
Name united;
From miami_airport;
To pasco;
Distance 1000;
Configuration air_travel;
}

Object train {
Name gas_train;
From beach;
To miami_airport;
Distance 30;
Configuration train_travel;
}
"""
sale_number = ''

sales = collections.defaultdict(list)

for line in status.split('\n'):
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith("set"):
         continue
    elif (line.startswith("Object") or line.startswith("object")):
         sale_number = line.split(' ')[1].strip()
    elif not line or line.isspace() :
         continue
    else:
         # you can also use a regular expression here
         sales[sale_number].append(line.split())

for sale in sales:
    print sale+str(dict(sales[sale][:-1]))
```

and this generates:

```
car{'To': 'Seattle;', 'Configuration': 'road_travel;', 'From': 'Richland;', 'Name': 'honda;', 'Distance': '160;'}
train{'To': 'miami_airport;', 'Configuration': 'train_travel;', 'From': 'beach;', 'Name': 'gas_train;', 'Distance': '30;'}
aeroplane{'To': 'pasco;', 'Configuration': 'air_travel;', 'From': 'miami_airport;', 'Name': 'united;', 'Distance': '1000;'}
bus{'To': 'richland;', 'Configuration': 'road_travel;', 'From': 'pasco;', 'Name': 'greyhound;', 'Distance': '15;'}
```

and I want to convert the above python output into a picture that looks something like below. I don't want to do it manually using Giffy or MS-Visio because my practical cases have about 1000 objects (this example has 4 objects in "status")
[image: flow_chart of above dictionary]

Comment: @Jivan The way I have been doing is I wrote a python script that converts the file with content in "status" into a .dot file, then I import it into graphviz to visualize it. As the number of objects increase, this gets huge and complicated, so I thought to convert the content into a graphic eliminating graphviz approach. So far I converted the file content into dictionaries and I want to import "key" and "values" into tkinter or D3 or some other visualization library (python or javascript) but I am not sure how that can be done.

Comment: @Jivan I also tried using "pydot" library following the examples in http://pythonhaven.wordpress.com/2009/12/09/generating_graphs_with_pydot/ but a lot of it involved hard-coding which is not helpful in this problem

Answer (score 1):

Focusing just on converting your weirdly-formatted `status` string into a `dict` is hard enough couldn't you have it in a more sensible, popular format like JSON?

```
import re
def Status2dict(status):
    result = {}
    current = {}
    lines = status.splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line: 
            continue
        mo = re.match(r'Object (\w+) {', line)
        if mo:
            curk = mo.group(1)
            current = {curk: {}}
        elif re.match('}', line):
            result.update(current)
            current = {}
        else:
            mo = re.match(r'(\w+)\s+([\w\s]+);', line)
            if not mo:
                raise ValueError('cannot match {!r}'.format(line))
            current[curk][mo.group(1)] = mo.group(2)
    if current:
        result.update(current)
    return result

import pprint    
pprint.pprint(Status2dict(status))
```

This code tries to be marginally robust on small variations from the inferred syntax, you may want to dial that up **or** down, depending.  But, it should be better than nothing.

Comment: I tried this. It is not working. `current` dictionary is always empty so never entering the `if current` case. First line is `Object car {` and since `current` is empty and there is no `}` it hits the `else` and again doing a `re.match` and failing because `{` is not in it. and so nothing is ever written to `curk`. can you please take a look?

Comment: commenting `if current` eliminated the error and generated a JSON file generated the output I added to your answer. Why did you use `if current` check?

Comment: @SrinGupta , fixed indentation now.  You're right that the `if current:` check is supererogatory as `result.update({})` is a no-op anyway, eliminating it now for simplicity.

Comment: I have a question: if my object name has `_`, the program fails. So, I changed the first `mo=re.match(...)` but looks like I am doing something horribly wrong and not able to match if the object name has any underscores. (NOTE: I changed the first `mo` similar to second `mo`... an example of what i mean is: if the object line looks like: `object aeroplane_unit_crew` or `object bus_set etc`.

Comment: To match only `Object` lines which are not `Object _ {` could be done in many simple ways, but it's not clear what you want to occur to the rest of that block in such cases.  Comments are cramped: best to edit the Q, showing exactly the code you're using now, what it does, what you'd like it to do instead; even better would be to accept this A, which **does** solve the Q you posed after all!, and open a new one for this new issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you already got the code converting to dot file, you can use the tk export of graphviz to visualise your graph on a tkinter canvas. You could give a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759878/is-there-an-interactive-graphing-library-for-python) for other libraries.

`dot -Ttk` output tcl code like this

```
# a
$c create oval 5.33 53.33 77.33 5.33 -fill white -width 1 -outline black -tags {1node1}
$c create text 41.33 30.3 -text {a} -fill black -font {"Times" 14} -tags {0node1}
# c
$c create oval 53.33 149.33 125.33 101.33 -fill white -width 1 -outline black -tags {1node2}
$c create text 89.33 126.3 -text {c} -fill black -font {"Times" 14} -tags {0node2}
#(...)
```

You can display it on a tkinter canvas by calling the tcl interpreter as in this example:

```
from Tkinter import *
import subprocess

graph = "digraph g { a-> c ; b -> c ; c -> d }"

ps = subprocess.Popen(('dot', '-Ttk'),stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = ps.communicate(input=graph)

canvas = Canvas()
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

#the output of graphiz assume thazt the canvas in variable $c
out = "set c .{}\n".format(canvas._name) + out
#tk.eval expect command one by one
map(canvas.tk.eval, out.split("\n"))

canvas.mainloop()
```

Comment: As of now I have been doing something similar. I wrote a python script to convert the "status" into a .dot file, then I import into GraphVIZ to get the flowchart/graph but I am trying to get away from that. After some reading, I thought by converting that to `JSON`, I can then somehow visualize it in D3 or using some python library because eventually I want to convert it into an interactive graphic.